# How to get File Size from http request to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

[image]

In my http request to SharePoint block, I want to show the file size field as the image above, however I can't really find what should be the name of it. I have tried something like $select=FileSize but it doesn't seems to work.

My current Uri:
_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('')}')/Items?$select=*,FileLeafRef,FileDirRef,**FileSize**&$filter=FSObjType eq 1

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `File Size` column for a `Folder` item is in the property `ItemCount` of the `Folder`.

So, your REST query should be:

```
https://your-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/your-site/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('your-list')/Items?$select=FileRef,Folder/ItemCount&$expand=Folder&$filter=FSObjType eq 1
```

Meaning:

- you must expand `Folder`
- you must select `Folder/ItemCount`